# Encoding special chars issue: one of four params ignored in API GET request

Tags: angular, http, parameters, get

I have these dynamic values (params) that are sent to an API, so I can get a PNG image after inserting a formatted text (size and color) in a input:

```
params = {
    "handwriting_id": "8X3WQ4D800B0",
    "text": "",
    "handwriting_size": "",
    "handwriting_color": "",
  }
```

The first two are required, not the third and fourth. My issue is that the last parameter (color) is being ignored, unlikely the others: I get the image with the size I choose and the text I write, but not with the color, which comes always in black. This is the relevant HTML:

```
<mat-form-field class="block center">
    <mat-select placeholder="Choose Color" [(ngModel)]="selectedColor" [(ngModel)]="params.handwriting_color" (change)="changeColor()">
      <mat-option value="#FF0000" selected="selected">Red

      </mat-option>
      <mat-option value="#8c30ec">Blue
      </mat-option>
      <mat-option value="#ec30db">Violet
      </mat-option>

    </mat-select>
  </mat-form-field>
```

And this is the URL custom string with the call and those params:

```
const url = 
      `https://api.handwriting.io/render/png?handwriting_id=${this.params.handwriting_id}&text=${this.params.text}&handwriting_size=${this.params.handwriting_size}&handwriting_color=${this.params.handwriting_color}`;
```

Honestly, I don't get it; why is just one param being ignored? Any help would be appreciated

EDIT:

As @Fateh Mohamed suggested I tried this:

```
params = {
    "handwriting_id": "8X3WQ4D800B0",
    "text": "",
    "handwriting_size": "",
    "handwriting_color": "",
  }
  color = encodeURIComponent(this.params.handwriting_color);
```

and then pass it to the URL:

```
const url = 
      `https://api.handwriting.io/render/png?handwriting_id=${this.params.handwriting_id}&text=${this.params.text}&handwriting_size=${this.params.handwriting_size}&handwriting_color=${this.color}`;
```

But still no results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please use :

```
encodeURIComponent(uri);
```

to encode special characters

Comment: I'm sorry @Fateh Mohamed, but after all..I tried this: `const uri =`  
      `https://api.handwriting.io/render/png?handwriting_id=${this.params.handwriting_id}&text=${this.params.text}&handwriting_size=${this.params.handwriting_size}&handwriting_color=${this.params.handwriting_color}`;
    `const url = encodeURIComponent(uri);`  but the color still doesnt changes... what am I doing wrong?

Comment: ok try to encode the color variable only and not all the uri and in the end use the encoded color in the uri: like this: encodeURIComponent(params.handwriting_color);

Comment: it works now, encoding the special var, thanks, very apreciated!